# Trying to embed a base64 JPG in a SVG to post to twitter

Tags: php, svg, twitter, bots

In http://cheapbotsdonequick.com/ I'm trying to make a bot that publishes images. It uses SVG and when I use some placeholder service like placecage dot com (that gives me a JPG) the thing runs OK and the tweet goes through with the image. I did a placeholder script and the image appears in CBDQ but the tweet appears with a question mark. The SVG needs the image encoded as base64. I started to make a simpler one, just to convert and use it in the svg tag, but it doesn't work:

```
svg <svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" version=\"1.1\" width=\"1024\" height=\"512\" style=\"position: relative; background: white;\"><image x=\"0\" y=\"0\" width=\"1024\" height=\"482\" xlink:href=\"/x/myimagescript.php\" id=\"img\" /></svg>
```

Code:

```
<?php
// PHP placeholder images

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');    

$data = file_get_contents("image_placeholders/44721_tiger_lg.jpg");
$base64 = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . base64_encode($data);

//$jpegimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($base64);
//imagejpeg($jpegimage);

echo $base64;

?>
```

So, how can I create a proper image to embed into a SVG that could be posted to twitter?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: You can't. [Twitter doesn't support SVG uploads.](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media#imagerecs)

Comment: I'd suggest change to `data:image/jpeg;base64` jpg->jpeg

Comment: the issue is about the encoding of the image as a JPG. If I use 
`
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$data = file_get_contents("image_placeholders/44721_tiger_lg.jpg");
$base64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo $base64;`

It doesn't work. If I use:
`
$data = file_get_contents("image_placeholders/44721_tiger_lg.jpg");
$base64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($data);

echo '<img src="' . $base64 . '" />';
`
it works and show the image (but is not a JPG that i could embed in the SVG).